# Find the uncommon elements from two sets

Tags: java, performance, set

I am trying to find the uncommon elements from two sets in Java. Here is my way:

```
private void findUnCommon{

    Set<Integer> a = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
    Set<Integer> b = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(3, 4, 5, 6));
    // get all elements from set a and set b

    System.out.println("Before..");
    System.out.println("a is : " + a);
    System.out.println("b is : " + b);

    Set<Integer> result = new HashSet<>(a);
    result.removeAll(b);
    System.out.println("result is : " + result);

    Set<Integer> temp = new HashSet<>(b);
    temp.removeAll(a);
    System.out.println("temp is : " + temp);

    result.addAll(temp);
    System.out.println("Uncommon elements of set a and set b is : "
        + result);

    System.out.println("After..");
    System.out.println("a is : " + a);
    System.out.println("b is : " + b);
}
```

I have declared two extra sets.  Can this be improved?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is this a method?  You can't just plop code anywhere in Java.

The name of the operation is [symmetric difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference), so you should probably call it that.

Here's a more compact implementation.

```
private Set<T> symmetricDifference(Set<T> a, Set<T> b) {
    Set<T> result = new HashSet<T>(a);
    for (T element : b) {
        // .add() returns false if element already exists
        if (!result.add(element)) {
            result.remove(element);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Now the above method will generate syntactical error for generic variable T. So change the method declaration to be like private <T> Set<T> symmetricDifference(Set<T> a, Set<T> b) {...}

Comment: @Vivek If the type variable `T` is introduced when the class is defined, it works as written.

Answer (score 7):

With [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/) ([javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#disjunction%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable%29)):

```
CollectionUtils.disjunction(a, b);
```

With [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) ([javadoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#symmetricDifference%28java.util.Set,%20java.util.Set%29)):

```
Sets.symmetricDifference(a, b);
```

See also: *Effective Java, 2nd edition*, *Item 47: Know and use the libraries* (The author mentions only the JDK's built-in libraries but I think the reasoning could be true for other libraries too.)

Answer (score 3):

This should work faster:

```
private void findUnCommon{

    Set<Integer> a = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
    Set<Integer> b = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(3, 4, 5, 6));

    Set<Integer> result = new HashSet<>();
    for (Integer el: a) {
      if (!b.contains(el)) {
        result.add(el);
      }
    }
    for (Integer el: b) {
      if (!a.contains(el)) {
        result.add(el);
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Uncommon elements of set a and set b is : "
        + result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If data is ordered, as is the case in your example, you can use a merge-sort algorithm to do it while traversing each collection only once:

```
    List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
    List<Integer> b = Arrays.asList(3, 4, 5, 6);
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

    int ia = 0, ib = 0;

    while(ia<a.size() && ib<b.size()) {
        if (a.get(ia)<b.get(ib)) {
            result.add(a.get(ia));
            ia++;
        } else if (a.get(ia)>b.get(ib)) {
            result.add(b.get(ib));
            ib++;
        } else {
            ia++;
            ib++;
        }
    }
    result.addAll(a.subList(ia, a.size()));
    result.addAll(b.subList(ib, b.size()));

    System.out.println("Uncommon elements of set a and set b is : " + result);
```

If an actual `java.util.Set` is required, instead of any collection that in this case behaves as a set, one may use a `java.util.SortedSet` implementation (e.g., `java.util.TreeSet`). The code above can be directly translated to iterators by using a `PeekableIterator` wrapper. Without `peek()`, it requires a little more effort to advance each iterator only when needed.

Comment: HashSets are never ordered, even if parameter lists in their constructors are.

Comment: The question seems to be about sets in general, not specifically about hashing (check the title). Sets can be represented with ordered data structures and I was precisely pointing out the usefulness of doing so here. I changed my reply to emphasize that the assumption is on the data, not on HashSets.